# Excel False Result to Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this Formula:

```
=IF((N11)<$L11;"Underutilised";IF(AND((N11)<$L11;(N11)>$M11);"Within Desired levels";IF((N11)>$M11;"Overutilised")))
```

it works fine, but there are values that return to False. I would like to add a line in the formula that replaces tha FALSE to text "Within Desired Levels"
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a typo in your question.

However, the below would work

```
=IF((N11<$M11);"Within Desired levels";IF((N11)>$M11;"Overutilised";"Within Desired Levels"))
```

Just check the first part `=IF((N11<$M11)` this is where I think you typed the wrong operator.